# In org-mode, how to exclude a heading from export only for some back-ends?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

In org-mode, I can exclude a code blocks from HTML export with something like this:

```
#+header: :eval (eval (if (string= org-export-current-backend "html") "no" "yes")))
#+begin_src R
  1+1
#+end_src
```

How can I achieve the same for a heading and its contents? Something like a conditional `noexport` tag. I have tried to use similar `elisp` code in the `PROPERTY` drawer but this and several variations did not work:

```
* Section
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT: (eval (if (string= org-export-current-backend "html") "no" "yes")))
:END:
```

I have also tried to set a `TAGS` property to `noexport` or `:noexport:`

Comment: The (original) answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/75510/26163) might help you on your way...

Comment: Thanks, following that link led me here: https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/12/08/Selectively-exporting-headlines-in-org-mode/ and based on that I got my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer based on dalanicolai's comment, which led me [here](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/12/08/Selectively-exporting-headlines-in-org-mode/). I tag the headings that I don't want to export to, say, latex with `noexport_latex` and I also define this hook to add to `org-export-before-parsing-hook`:

```
(defun exclude-from-latex-export-hook (backend)
  (setq org-export-exclude-tags (remove "noexport_latex" org-export-exclude-tags))
  (if (string= backend "latex")
  (push "noexport_latex" org-export-exclude-tags)))
```

This uses the standard selective export mechanism but modifies the list of excluded tags on the fly depending on the export backend.

Comment: Ah great, I guess you peeked at @NickD's answer then also. I did not have much time to look into it, but I remembered that question/answer was very much related. Nice that it 'worked out well'! And thanks for sharing the solution, of course...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! I did something similar for including/excluding sections in slides when using [Org-Reveal](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal). I thought it could be useful if I include my variant as an answer.

I put this in my `.emacs` for the effect that sections tagged `:noslide:` are not included in the Reveal.js presentation, while sections tagged `:slide:` are included *only* in the presentation (and not when the document is exported to HTML or LaTeX or whatever).

```lisp
(defun exclude-slide-or-noslide (backend)
  (setq org-export-exclude-tags
        (cons (if (eq backend 'reveal) "noslide" "slide")
              (seq-remove (lambda (tag) (string-suffix-p "slide" tag)) org-export-exclude-tags))))

(add-hook 'org-export-before-parsing-functions #'exclude-slide-or-noslide)
```